# MS-Projects -- Assigning a Resource group as resource

Tags: ms-project, resource-planning

I am using MS Projects (desktop) and am wondering if it is possible to assign resources by the group they are designated under in the resource list. Essentially I would like to assign a team to a project task instead of having to select the team members individually for these specific group of tasks.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to assign resources by group?

**No, assignments are made at the resource level.** An assignment is one resource and one task. A task may have many resource assignments and a resource can be assigned to many tasks.

> I would like to assign a team to a project task

**This can be done easily.** It is common to set up a team as a resource rather than list the members individually. If you have 3 engineers and 8 technicians, your schedule would have 2 resources: "engineer" with a max units of 3 and "technicians" with a max units of 8.